# Code Blocks auto completion working partly

Tags: codeblocks

I have a problem with autocompletion in Code Blocks. Let's say that I'm creating my own header file - it has  library - then I'm creating .cpp file and I include there header, I had previously created. After I create vector I should be able to see methods, that are included in  library, but there are none, though if I type them, they work - does any of you encontered that problem and foud the sollution? I'm wroking on version 20.03.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks 20.03 is very old, and the original codecompletion is stupid. I suggest you using a latest Nightly Build of CodeBlocks, its codecompletion is improved, and it has introduced a smart code completion plugin using Clangd to providehigh-quality code real-time analysis and intellicompletion. See here: [CodeBlocks Nightlies](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=20.0) and here: [CodeCompletion using Clangd and LSP](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,24357.0.html).